# Function doesn't update HTML as expected

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a onmousedown="toggleMore(this)" attached to it.  It goes to a function:

```
function toggleMore(divid){

alert(divid.id);
$('#'+divid.id).html('less');

}
```

This produces the correct dive id.  However the function doesn't change the html of the div.

I've played about with this but can't get it to work

Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: $(this).html("less");

Comment: TypeError: $(...).html is not a function is the response to $(this).html ...

Comment: That code in the question should work (although its a very inelegant approach to the problem). What happens when you run it? What does the console say?

Comment: Have you included jQuery? Or tried simply `$(divid).html('less')`?

Comment: so I thought the code should work too!  for some reason it's giving the TypeError saying that it's not a function.  However I've checeked and jquery is loaded

Comment: What, precisely, is not a function? `toggleMore`? `$`? Something else? How have you checked that jQuery is loaded? Have you looked at your developer tools' Net tab to ensure that you get a successful HTTP response for the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment in this answer, I can think of two easy ways to do this.

First way is using html data-* attributes and the JQuery .data() function.

```js
$("#DivOne").on("click", function()
{
    var targetID = $(this).data("target-id");
    
    $("#" + targetID).text("I told you so...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="DivOne" data-target-id="DivTwo">
    If click here
</div>

<div id="DivTwo">
    This text will change
</div>
```

But, if you need something like an [accordion effect](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=html+accordion+effect&oq=html+accordion+effect&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1007j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=html+accordion), you can do the following way:

```js
// First we hide the content of every block
$(".block .content").hide();

// Then, if the user click in a title
$(".block .title").on("click", function()
{
    // We hide the contents
    $(".block .content").hide();
  
    // And find the content div within the parent of the clicked title
    $(this).parent().find(".content").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
    <div class="title">Title A</div>
    <div class="content">Content A</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="title">Title B</div>
    <div class="content">Content B</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="title">Title C</div>
    <div class="content">Content C</div>
</div>
```

Of course you mix those methods, using data-* attributes to target multiple elements.

---

**Original answer**

You don't need to catch the id from the element...
JQuery do this job for you if you pass the whole element to it.

```js
function onMouseDown(element)
{
    $(element).text("Thank you!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onmousedown="onMouseDown(this)">
    Click me
</div>
```

---

Another way to do this is using "*pure*" JQuery to handle the click for you, like this:

```js
var div = $("#DivID");
div.on("mousedown", function(event)
{
    div.text("Thank you!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="DivID">
    Click me
</div>
```

Comment: @Downvoter, any comment that can help me improve this answer?

Comment: I think our OP is downvoting answers that don't meet his/her unclear expectations.

Comment: @isherwood, I was thinking the same. Thank you for the upvote (you deleted yours, so, I can't retribute...)

Comment: I haven't down voted any answers,  I'm just glad of any help since I can't figure out why it would work.  I don't know who is doing the down voting since some of the answers seem right on target to getting things sorted out

Comment: @user1616338, well, let's keep trying to solve the issue, then... Does my answer works for you? If not, whats is the problem?

Comment: so I have checked that jquery is there:  if(window.jQuery){ 

console.log('loaded'); 
}else{

console.log('not loaded');

}  - console shows loaded

Comment: I tried the more less code above and that works but I need to be able to reference the other div so I can do the show/hide part

Comment: I was mistaken. Apologies.

Comment: @user1616338, I've added some more examples to my answer... See if this fits you... =]